# Using MuiThemeProvider tag for material ui with react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I started with simple react components of material ui using demonstrative app as mentioned here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui
I have following questions

1. do we need to use MuiThemeProvider for each and
   evert material ui component ?
2. Is there any way to use it globally

This is working fine for given code. but when I add any additional component in MuiThemeProvider tag it does not render anything and webpack does not throw any error.

Lets have a look at below example. I simply copied MyAwesomeReactComponent twice and it stopped working. This is working fine if I remove second instance of MyAwesomeReactComponent.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

here is code of MyAwesomeReactComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const MyAwesomeReactComponent = () => (
  <RaisedButton label="Default" />
);

export default MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

Comment: Wrap up your components with div tag,  then use the the theme provider.

Comment: thanks, this helped.
Any idea if this is a bug in material ui implementation to use <div> tag ?

Comment: am not sure whether it's a bug or not but when you inject more than one component to `MuiThemeProvider` it wouldn't work that's because it expects only one react component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **do we need to use MuiThemeProvider for each and evert material ui component ?**

No,you dont need it.

> **Is there any way to use it globally?**

yes,you can use it globally.

Wrap you app (root) component  one in `MuiThemeProvider` component

```
//assuming app.js as root one

ReactDOM.render(
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <App /> 
    </MuiThemeProvider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

From here onwards,in your app.js  and in the nested or other component, you can include whatever theme you want.

e.g. AppBar in app.js

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

const AppBarExampleIcon = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
  />
);


export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (<div className="container"><AppBarExampleIcon /></div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does address my problem.
Also on further research, I found that another way to resolve this issue is simple wrap multiple meterial ui components in <div></div>